# changing const wchar_t* during runtime

Tags: c++

i have a string that i recieve from using std::cin and im trying to change a const wchar_t* to that variable

```
const wchar_t* TARGET_FILE = L"";
try {
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "DLL Name: ";
    getline(std::cin, str);
    //TARGET_FILE = str;
    std::string narrow_string(str);
    std::wstring wide_string = std::wstring(narrow_string.begin(), narrow_string.end());
    const wchar_t* result = wide_string.c_str();
    const wchar_t* TARGET_FILE = result;
    std::cout << TARGET_FILE; //Debug

}
catch (const std::exception & ex) {
    std::cout << "[ERROR] " << ex.what() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Press any key to exit..." << '\n';
    std::cin.get();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

When this code is executed this is what happens

```
DLL Name: Kinky.dll
0000020E11C61560[ERROR] DLL not found.
Press any key to exit...
```

i get 0000019CCB971300 instead of a valid text format  it works when i hard code the value of TARGET_FILE using

```
//constexpr auto TARGET_FILE      = L"Kinky.dll";
```

Sorry if im being a bit stupid but im not very familiar with what wchar_t vars are i just know the sdk im using requires one

Edit:
This section was pasted by me to try resolve the original issue so idk if its the correct usage if its not the correct usage im expecting this to be my issue

```
std::string narrow_string(str);
std::wstring wide_string = std::wstring(narrow_string.begin(), narrow_string.end());
const wchar_t* result = wide_string.c_str();
const wchar_t* TARGET_FILE = result;
```

Comment: is this really the code that produces the runtime error? You have two different `TARGET_FILE` variables, one shadowing the other, and changing the definition of the first should not have any impact

Comment: Use `std::wcout` to print wide characters.

Comment: You have TARGET_FILE as both a global and local variable.  That might have a lot to do with your issue.

Comment: perhaps the runtime error is only caused by code you do not show that assumes the first `TARGET_FILE` variable holds the filename, but in fact you never modify it. To be sure a [mcve] is required

Comment: try to put a `std::cout << TARGET_FILE; //Debug` outside of the try-catch, this should shed some light on the issue

Comment: I placed a std::cout before the try catch and it output this
00007FF6A958CAF0 im going to attempt to use std::wcout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of converting the string, you can read wide characters to begin with. Use `std::wcin` to read and `std::wcout` to print wide characters. You can keep the text as `std::wstring` and use `c_str()` when you call the function which requires `const wchar_t*`.

```
void function1(const wchar_t*);

void function2() {
    std::wstring str;
    getline(std::wcin, str);
    std::wcout << str;

    function1(str.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Thanks had to change around a few things in the rest of my code but this worked perfectly thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1) The potential problem is how you convert narrow to wide string. While you convert ASCII dll names everything is fine (or not? Only in practice I guess?). Otherwise there be dragons. Converting to wide characters is hard: you should somehow know the narrow encoding (UTF-8? System encoding?), wide characters encoding is also different on different platforms (USC-2 or UTF-16 on Windows, UTF-32 on Linux, native endianness). But this is different concern.

2) Correct answer (mentioned by @Ville-Valtteri) is that you cannot output `const wchar*` to `std::cout`. `cout` treats it as a pointer, and this `00007FF6A958CAF0` thing that you get is a pointer value. This is not what you want. Maybe you want to write to std::wcout, or convert back to narrow string; what you need depends on your actual real code.

Comment: All i needed was to reference the files name so i can load the dll onto another application, thanks for the more specific reason for my error

Comment: FWIW if you need std::string, you may try ANSI equivalents, like LoadLibraryA()